# correct way to create a 3d median numpy array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, median

so I tried to create a 3d array using numpy via this line:

```
self.dark_median_roi=np.median(self.dark_roi, axis=3)
```

where self.dark_roi is a multidimensional array and I got this error:

```
IndexError: axis 3 out of bounds (2)
```

I'm guessing I went about creating a 3d array the wrong way. What is the correct way to create a median numpy array? This will be running/is trying to run on a Raspberry pi, so I would rather avoid using loops, especially with arrays.

Edit:

so I corrected some mistakes from earlier in the code that weren't noticeable at first until I started adding print statements so this is the error I'm getting now:

```
IndexError: axis 3 out of bounds (3)
```

and I tried changing the the axis flag to 2 and it created a 2d array

Comment: `np.median(self.dark_roi, axis=2)`, because the axis index starts at `0`?

Comment: What's the shape of `self.dark_roi`?

Comment: the shape of self.dark_roi is (200,200,10)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 axes: 0, 1 and 2.
If you mean the last one  - enter axis=2.